# Dropbox service running, dropbox.py says not running

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, dropbox

On a Debian Squeeze 7.11 server, Dropbox seems to be running:

```
    service dropbox status
```

says that it is. Restarting appears successful. But running

```
    ./dropbox.py status
```

says Dropbox is not running. As does:

```
    dropbox status
```

What should I look at to resolve this?

Comment: What is `dropbox.py`? Did that come with Dropbox? Can you look in the source to see what it does?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py - it's a script that's supposed to allow commands to manage dropbox.